# custom mysql datadir ubuntu in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mysql

All,

I noticed that in Ubuntu 16.04 if I have a custom datadir (`/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`) the systemd service won't start because of `sanity()` check in `/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start`. The reason is that it always expect that your data is in */var/lib/mysql*

Is there a clean workaround to have a custom data folder ? I could potentially modify the unit definition to skip `ExecStartPre`, but it doesn't feel like a clean solution.

Comment: I would simply modify the sanity check in `mysql-systemd-start`. I think it should not assume that the data is in `/var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: yeah I did it, but since I manga stuff via puppet/ansible this can be painful since if they update the script I can have conflicts or loser important updates :(